# Ajax custom cart not applying shopping rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, gift-card

In my **ajax custom cart** after applying a **coupon code**, adding a **free gift product** to cart **programmatically**. That new product is not detected for **shopping rule validation**. But the product is available in quote table without having applied rule ids.

But in **default cart** after saving the new product to cart functions like **`collectTotals()`** is called which detects the new product.

Please advise me how to fix this or how to trigger **`checkout_cart_index`** event programmatically.

```
2018-06-05T11:51:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): DEFAULT CART:  FREE GIFT ADDED TO CART
2018-06-05T11:51:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): Event Triggered: checkout_cart_index
2018-06-05T11:51:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): predispatch() called....
2018-06-05T11:51:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): _getCart() called...
2018-06-05T11:51:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): _getCart() called...
2018-06-05T11:51:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): save()...called in Cart.php
2018-06-05T11:51:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): called by Mage_Checkout_CartController :: indexAction
```

Using the below code:

```
$cart->addProduct($product,$request);
$cart->save();
$this->_getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```